# Web Browsing Automation with Mathematica

Tags: interoperability, web-access, automation

I want to build a bot to automate web browsing, this mean something like:

- filling forms
- press "submit" buttons
- find certain text inside pages
- and so on...

How can I do this with *Mathematica*?

The `Import` function just make you download a single web page but it doesn't support cookies and similar things to build a complete automated bot, does *Mathematica* have some useful packet to do so?

Comment: If the form uses the GET method, submitting the form just means composing an URL (on which `Import` works).  The question is very general in this form, and I'd be inclined to say Mathematica is not the right tool for this (you'll end up using JLink or .NETLink anyway).  But if you can give a very specific example, we can think about how to implement it in Mathematica (or will be able to say with more confidence that it's not possible without external libraries)

Comment: Yes, I know that for a GET method I can simply compose the URL in the right way. I give you an example: suppose I want to make a little script to log-in to an online service, put some informations in a form to generate a report, download the report and then use Mathematica to analyze this, and I want to do it "one-click", without make the log-in and download manually!

Comment: I don't believe that this is possible in pure Mathematica.  Any working solution you might get will use external libraries, most likely through either JLink or .NETLink.  You might be able to drive a browser object through .NETLink on Windows, but I am not familiar with the technology.

Comment: if you need support for cookies then use `wget`. You can include it in Mma code by using `Run`. About to go to bed but do a search cause  posted something here in answer to another question a couple of weeks ago. ...here it is: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/downloading-files-without-using-import/1211#1211

Comment: For a bit of datamining on a website that Mathematica could not parse entirely (interactive java stuff) I used the [iMacros Plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/?src=search) and remote-controlled Firefox to do a few things with a suitable script. It is a bit circuitous (and not within Mathematica, so no answer) but worked fine once set up properly.

Comment: You can also try `curl`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6977128/695132

Comment: Yes, curl is nice: I use ``RunCurl[x_String, dir_:"C:\\directorywherecurlis\\"] := Module[{id = ToString[Round[AbsoluteTime[]]], run, res}, 
    run = Run2[StringJoin["%comspec% /c ", dir, "curl.exe ", x, " > ", dir, "curl", id, ".log 2>", id, "curl", id, ".err"]]; 
     res = Import[StringJoin[dir, "curl", id, ".log"], "Text"]; DeleteFile[StringJoin[dir, "curl", id, ".log"]]; 
     (If[FileExistsQ[#1], DeleteFile[#1]] & )[StringJoin[dir, "curl", id, ".err"]]; res];``

Comment: with ``Run2[cmd_String] := Module[{shell}, Switch[$OperatingSystem, "Windows", 
     If[$OperatingSystem === "Windows", Needs["NETLink`"]; shell = NETLink`CreateCOMObject["WScript.shell"]; ]; 
      shell[run[StringReplace[cmd, {"\n" -> "", "\r" -> ""}], 0, True]], "Unix", Run[cmd], "MacOSX", Run[cmd]]];``

Comment: Hi Rolf, can you put your comment in an answer with separated code? It's difficult to understand what you wrote in this way. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Francesco: But it is no answer. Just a note on http://stackoverflow.com/a/6977128/695132 , i.e., you get access to the log files.

Comment: I've failed in this before, especially w/r/t cookies. When trying to find text, I just use `Import[x,"Source"]` where x is the site (all manually downloaded w/ wget) and then find content using `StringCases[]` i.e. `trlist = StringCases[pagetext, Shortest["<tr>" ~~ ___ ~~ "</tr>"]];` (which would find all text within rows in a page arranged in that way, for example)

Comment: Yes I've used `curl` for FTP-ing Mma content but it was only once or twice. `wget` is something I use regularly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manipulate web pages on Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/how-to-manipulate-web-pages-on-mathematica)

Comment: @Francesco Please see an answer here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/how-to-manipulate-web-pages-on-mathematica

Comment: @szabolcs, how can this be a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/how-to-manipulate-web-pages-on-mathematica when this question is older? I suspect it is the other way around! ;). Either way we ought to either close this or have someone write up a suitable answer. If nobody does by tomorrow night, I'll go ahead and summarize all of what has been said in a community wiki answer.

Comment: @nixeagle It doesn't matter which one is older.  The point is: the other question has a good answer which I think answers this as well as possible.  A concrete example always helps.  Others think this needs a general solution, not relying on a concrete example so it's still open.  Also, I voted to close because that'd ensure that anyone finding this question will immediately be pointed to a good answer.

Comment: @nixeagle Also, closing as duplicate is *not* penalizing the OP and is not a bad point for the OP.  It's for keeping the site clean and useful for future visitors.  This also applies to your `ValueQ` question---originally I voted to close because I thought it had been asked, not because it's a bad question (it is a good question).  (Just to avoid any misunderstanding on why I vote to close.)

Comment: I'm eager to see the improvements made to `Import[]` in version 9!

Comment: @Francesco On what platform are you?

Comment: did you see any improvements in 9, i have it, but still struggling with this exact issue!   Any thoughts on weather i should take Jlink or curl? im thinking JLink has more support and may be more guided to websites? If you guys have any good resources or blogs let me know! thank you!!

Answer (score 39):

Here is a package which does what you want:

https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/webunit

Clone the repository from github, and place the `WebUnit` folder under `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`

To use it:

1. `` Needs["WebUnit`"] ``
2. `InstallWebUnit[]` (* launches chromedriver.exe *)
3. `StartWebSession[]` (* launches Chrome web browser, assuming you have that installed *)
4. `OpenWebPage["http://mathematica.stackexchange.com"]` (* opens the web page *)
5. `ClickElement[Id["nav-users"]]` (* clicks the web element 'nav-users' the users tab *)

And then `TypeElement` works similarly (assuming you have an input field with an id).

Edit: You can also use `JavascriptExecute["alert('hi');"]` to execute arbitrary javascript (in this example case it brings up the alert dialog).

Comment: Great application! But could you provide a WebUnit documentation in a pdf file? On my computer the provided documentation does not open properly. I am not sure whether the directory structure in the provided bundle is OK. BTW: is it possible to set a value to a RadioButton?

Comment: @Arnoud Buzing Can you provide a minimal example of how to use `Execute[]` to run some javascript? I can find this function in the `WebUnit` source code. There is no documentation so I am asking you here.

Comment: This works for me: Execute["alert('hi');"]

Comment: The link above seems to be broken. Is there an update?

Comment: @GregH, I put a new version with a new link in the post above (not sure how this disappeared). Also, in this new version I renamed the function Execute to JavascriptExecute (more precise function name).

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing Are there any new functionalities added in the new version?

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing Tried to follow your steps above, but when I run `InstallWebUnit[]` I get the error message "Windows cannot find 'C:\Program'." I wonder if it is trying to access "C:\Program Files\..." but the space is messing things up. Any suggestions?

Comment: @GregH Do you have the "WebUnit" directory directly under $UserBaseDirectory/Applications?

Comment: @GregH Also, please try re-downloading it (I think I uploaded an older version earlier today). If you run `filehash webunit-master.zip` you should get `a15a9b82812999e2`

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing I unzipped the folder to `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\AddOns\Applications` as that seemed appropriate. I get the same error as before with the new .zip file. Also, this second version isn't as "clean" as the first; the first was only the folder `WebUnit` zipped; the latter has this folder, plus `Tests` and a few other files. (Hope that makes sense.)

Comment: @GregH OK, I've uploaded a new link which only contains WebUnit. Don't put anything under your installation directory, the appropriate location is `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`. If that does not work, let me know.

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing Got it to work. Thanks! Now more questions: on the form I am trying to use, pressing `Enter` activates the "Submit" button, which unfortunately doesn't have an ID to use the `ClickElement` command with. Is there a way to do a generic `TypeElement` that has the same effect as pressing the `Enter` key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27234/discussion-between-gregh-and-arnoud-buzing).

Comment: The link in the post is broken again.  Could you please update it?  Also, have you considered adding it to http://packagedata.net/ ?

Comment: A victim of my cloud object cleanup project ... I put a new package link above. This also adds support for the new Microsoft Edge browser.

Comment: Is this package Windows only?

Comment: It includes the chromedriver binaries for Mac and Linux as well, so this should work (if it doesn't work for you, let me know and I will try to fix it)

Comment: How can I get the package to integrate into the documentation centre, so that the documentation will be readable?  (Opening the notebooks directly shows something ugly.) I don't have experience with the application structure needed for this ...

Comment: I went ahead and added it to PackageData.net.  Feel free to edit, you can log it with your SE account! http://packagedata.net/index.php/#package-182

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing Please take a look on [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119472/280) question of mine. Also the latest version of Chrome produces a warning about unsupported command-line flag when is launched via `StartWebSession`. Are there any updates for the package?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, I replied to your question. You can ignore the unsupported command-line flag warning, I just haven't figured out how to configure Chrome to not complain about that.

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing I have solved the unsupported command-line flag warning problem just by downloading the latest release of the [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) (currently it is [2.22](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.22/)) and placing it into the appropriate directory instead of the existing file chromedriver.exe (which comes as a part of the package)!

Comment: I put this package on github  (see answer) and updated to the latest versions (2.25) of chromedriver.