# Access interactive web forms

Tags: import, html

I would like to communicate with interactive web forms, e.g., get the same HTML response as if I had clicked a "select" button and then clicked a "submit" button on a web page. This is for automated download of scientific data from an archive. The "select" button is HTML coded as follows:

```
<input id="ibmarkpublic" class="markpublic" type="button" value="MarkPublic">
```

The "submit" button is coded as follows:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Request selected datasets" onclick="retrieve.action='http://dataportal.examplesite.org/rh/confirmation'; return true;">
```

The actions refer to javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wdb/jslib/wdb_result_functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> ....
</script>
```

and there's the following statement at the head of the table of data items:

```
<form name="retrieve" method="POST" action="http://dataportal.examplesite.org/rh/confirmation">
```

I've tried using code of the kind

```
Import[url, "Data", "RequestMethod" -> "POST", "RequestParameters" -> {"MarkPublic"-> "True", "submit" -> "True"}]
```

but couldn't succeed receiving the same HTML answer as when clicking the two buttons by hand in the browser. Is the "RequestMethod" option documented anywhere?

Comment: Closely related: [91899](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91899/731)

Comment: Also related: [(2362)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2362/142).