# Importing from a web page that seems to expect specific browsers

Tags: import, web-access

I've successfully and fruitfully imported data from web sites before, but now seem to have a particularly troublesome site that I would like to access through *Mathematica* on my MacBook.

```
Import[site="https://auctionfiling.fcc.gov/form175/search175/index.htm"]
```

returns the error:

```
FetchURL::httperr: The request to URL 
https://auctionfiling.fcc.gov/form175/search175/index.htm was not successful.
The server returned the HTTP status code 500 ("Internal Server Error").
```

Exploring further, the command `URLExecute[site]` returns an long exception report that includes the text:

```
<cflog text="#Variables.errorTemplate#: UnsupportedBrowser The
browser you are using is not supported. <br>The error occurred on
line 32." type="error">
```

Further text indicates that the site requires either: Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.5 (or higher), Netscape 6 (or higher), Opera 6 (or higher), or Mozilla. Though I've successfully used it with Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

Is there a way around this? I am wanting to pull down many thousands of FCC license records through this approach.

Alternatively, perhaps there is an approach of running an external browser linked with *Mathematica*?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Steve

Comment: To spoof the user agent string: `URLRead[HTTPRequest["https://auctionfiling.fcc.gov/form175/search175/index.htm", <|"UserAgent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"|>], "Body"]` or whatever [other user agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) you want to use.

Comment: @J.M. I think that should be an answer.

Comment: @J.M. With your code *Mathematica* sends `User-Agent: Wolfram HTTPClient 11.1` (*Mathematica* 11.1.1). The same is with version 11.0.1 (the string is `User-Agent: Wolfram HTTPClient 11.`). Looks like currently this functionality is broken. :(

Comment: @Alexey, for reference, how did you test that the spoof is not working? I just tried in 11.1.1, and I was able to get through the browser-based block.

Comment: @J.M. I used the built-in logger of [HandyCache](http://handycache.ru/) free local proxy-server. Of course, I first configured *Mathematica* to work through the proxy.

Comment: @J.M. I get `"StatusCode" -> 404` both with and without the proxy. The body contains "Error Occurred While Processing Request". I'm on Windows 7 x64. Do you get the same response as with a browser (Firefox opens the "Auction Application Search" form page)?

Comment: @Alexey, I'm on Xubuntu 16.04 (Xenial), and using Opera 41, and I can access the FCC webpage given by the OP. Here's the complete working code I used on 11.1: `ImportString[URLRead[HTTPRequest["https://auctionfiling.fcc.gov/form175/search175/index.htm", <|"UserAgent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/43.0.2442.1144"|>], "Body"], "HTML"]`.

Comment: @J.M. I've found that the failure was caused by hidden Unicode characters inside of the URL copied from your first comment (with the second comment the situation is even worse what helped me to figure out what happens). After fixing the URL now it works for me. But user-agent according to HandyCache is still `User-Agent: Wolfram HTTPClient 11.1`... May be `"UserAgent"` is used *after* the secure connection with the server is established? HandyCache reports only the header of initial `CONNECT` request.

Answer (score 2):

Posting [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146240/importing-from-a-web-page-that-seems-to-expect-specific-browsers#comment393024_146240) as an answer, you can specify the user agent string in `HTTPRequest` directly via `"UserAgent"` (here it is for Firefox 40.1 taken from [this](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) site):

```
URLRead[HTTPRequest[
  "https://auctionfiling.fcc.gov/form175/search175/index.htm", <|
   "UserAgent" -> 
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"|>]]
```

> [image: output]

(note that the code in the comments is broken due to hidden Unicode characters).

It is worth to know [that](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HTTPRequest.html)

> The default `"UserAgent"` is typically `"Wolfram HTTP Client xxxx"`, where `xxxx` is a version number.

Comment: How odd; it seems posting the code as a comment does munge the URL. Tsk...

Comment: Alexey Popkov, Thank you for the very helpful insights. I was not aware of the HTTPRequest function. This has been very helpful for more days of progress.  I'm now confused on a deeper level.  I'm not at all knowledgable about XML but I've used hints from the answer to another question similar to this ( https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/how-to-manipulate-web-pages-on-mathematica)   But I'm still unable to set parameters in my request with Import[$req, "Data", "RequestMethod" -> "Post",  "RequestParameters" -> {aucSelect"->1002}].  I'm now floundering, but grateful.

Comment: @Stephen That's entirely different question, you shouldn't discuss it here. Instead, create another well-formed question on this issue.

Comment: Quite right. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

> Alternatively, perhaps there is an approach of running an external browser linked with Mathematica?

This seems to be possible since v12.0, using [`WebExecute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WebExecute.html). You can find it in [the new-features page of v12](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn12.html), under "Controlling Web Browsers" and described shortly as "execute commands in a web browser".

I don't know whether this would have been sufficient for your purposes (and, I would suspect, it's too late for your original task). But it's an interesting option to consider for similar problems.