# Is it possible to use Mathematica's Twitter integration to unfollow a certain list of users?

Tags: social-media

I read [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/Twitter.html), It's not clear to me if there is absolutely no way to unfollow people with it or if there is some sneaky way to do that. I ask that because in the past, I asked [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2362/603) and it seemed that Mathematica could interact with webpages and as I didn't understand it very well, I don't know if using this web page interaction, it would be possible to issue a command to unfollow people in a Twitter account.

Comment: I understand why this will be closed. It is really too vague. But a downvote? That I do not understand. I may have to upvote just as a counterweight.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It's not clear to me why it's vague. Mathematica has [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/Twitter.html) I looked at the documentation and didn't found a command to delete tweets. So, I was trying to confirm: Is that it or there is some sneaky way to do that?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I edited it in a - hopefully - more meaningful way.

Comment: Yes, this does look more like a viable MSE question.