# How to download tables from a url?

Tags: import, list-manipulation, web-access

I'm trying to import all the tables on a website, this one in particular:

- https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

For local files that are already tabular, `Import[#, "Table"]` works well, but I can't seem to easily import simple tables embbeded in a sites.

Comment: At first glance, you may need to look outside of Mathematica for this one. It looks like the prices are generated with JS, onload. Selenium makes a Java package you could most likely wrap into Mathematica.

Comment: If you know the basics of CSS selectors and HTML, then you can download the website after the prices have been loaded and use [jSoupLink](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71914/extract-information-from-html-using-css-selectors) on your downloaded files.

Comment: @Pickett that's a good idea!

Comment: @PeterRoberge I'm looking into other platforms... but I would think URLFetchAsynchronous[] could handle this?

Comment: @M.R. I'm not sure- from the documentation it isn't clear if the JS calls are virtualized. The only implementation I've seen personally implement GUI-less browser actions is the [HtmlUnitDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.html)

Comment: @PeterRoberge There is a package called [`WebUnit`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69343/731) that can do this. Without that there is no way that Mathematica can evaluate JavaScript.

Comment: When I said "...download the website after the prices have been loaded" I meant going to the website in the browser, download it and then import it from the hard drive. This seems to me the easiest option if it's just a one time thing.

Comment: Amazon loads a JavaScript file which contains the data in JSON format with a JavaScript 'callback'. For example for Linux the file is http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/ec2/linux-od.min.js   You could parse this file and the other files similarly to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer because it turns out the AWS JSON is surprisingly complicated. Anyways this might help you get there eventually. Lots of work left unfortunately.

```
str = Import["http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/ec2/linux-od.min.js", "String"];
pos = StringPosition[str, "callback"];
obj = StringTake[str, {pos[[1, 2]] + 2, StringLength[str] - 2}];
json = StringReplace[obj, ":" -> "->"];
json = StringReplace[json, "{" -> "<|"];
json = StringReplace[json, "}" -> "|>"];
json = StringReplace[json, "[" -> "{"];
json = StringReplace[json, "]" -> "}"];
json = ToExpression[json];
```

- Import the JavaScript file pointed to on the webpage that contains the data.
- Extract the JSON part (getting rid of JavaScript stuff, comments, etc)
- String replace JSON parts to Mathematica equivalents and to turn this into a Mathematica Association with ToExpression.

Now we have an association. We can now access the data in a hierarchical manner e.g.

```
json[config][regions][[1]][instanceTypes][[1]][sizes][[1]]
```

which gives us the result:

```
<|size -> "t2.micro", vCPU -> "1", ECU -> "variable",
memoryGiB -> "1", storageGB -> "ebsonly",
valueColumns -> {<|name -> "linux", prices -> <|USD -> "0.013"|>|>}|>
```