# Web Browsing Automation: how to expand all comments under a blog post?

Tags: interoperability, .netlink, web-access, automation

I wish to expand all the comments under a [LiveJournal](http://www.livejournal.com/) post for the purposes of saving the complete thread of comments. According to LiveJournal's [FAQ](http://www.livejournal.com/support/faq/62.html) when a post gets more than 50 comments they are automatically collapsed and LiveJournal doesn't provide an easy way to expand them: there is no <kbd>Expand All</kbd> button and the user must stupidly click on the every <kbd>Expand</kbd> button on the web page in order to get finally all the comments expanded. I wish to automate this process using either [`WebUnit`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69343/280) or directly through `NETLink` using COM/.NET interface of Chrome (or other browser).

As an example post with collapsed comments I suggest this (but feel free to take any other post if you wish):

http://suggestions.livejournal.com/825341.html

---

So far I have tried `WebUnit` as follows without luck:

```
Needs["WebUnit`"]
InstallWebUnit[]
StartWebSession[];

OpenWebPage["http://suggestions.livejournal.com/825341.html"]
ClickElement[Id["t12335869"]]
```

The `Id` `"t12335869"` in the above I have found via inspection of the HTML source of the first <kbd>Expand</kbd> button on that web page:

```
 <li class=" b-leaf-actions-item b-leaf-actions-expandchilds   " data-tid="t12335869">   <a target="_self" href="http://suggestions.livejournal.com/825341.html?thread=12335869#t12335869" rel="nofollow" class="b-pseudo">Expand</a>   </li>
```

I have tried also interfacing Internet Explorer via the COM interface but haven't found a way to make the `click[]` method working:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];
ie = CreateCOMObject["InternetExplorer.Application"];
ie@visible = True;
ie@Navigate["http://suggestions.livejournal.com/825341.html"];
doc = ie@Document;
While[ie@Busy || doc@readyState =!= "complete", Pause[.1]];
all = doc@all;
elems = all@tags@"a";
Table[If[elems@item[i]@innerText === "Expand", elems@item[i]@click[]; 
  i, ## &[]], {i, 0, elems@length - 1}] // Length
```

> ```
> 50
> ```

From the above it is seen that 50 hyperlinks with text "Expand" are found. But executing `click[]` on them changes nothing.

---

**How can I automate clicking the <kbd>Expand</kbd> buttons with *Mathematica*?**

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way to do it, using WebUnit:

```
Needs["WebUnit`"];
InstallWebUnit[];
StartWebSession[];
OpenWebPage["http://suggestions.livejournal.com/825341.html"];
```

Then, use `JavascriptExecute` to get all the links in the document and select only the ones that have the text EXPAND in them:

```
expandLinks = Flatten @ JavascriptExecute["
   var links = document.links;
   var result = []; 
   cnt=0; 
   for(i=0; i<links.length; i++) { 
    if( links[i].text=='Expand' ) { 
     result[cnt++] = links[i]; 
     } 
    };
   return result"]
```

Finally, click on all the `expandLinks`:

```
ClickElement["ELEMENT" /. #] & /@ Take[expandLinks, All]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works but for some reason for the given webpage it expands all comments only on the second evaluation of the line `ClickElement["ELEMENT" /. #] & /@ Take[expandLinks, All]`. For some other web pages it requires 3 - 6 times to go through the cycle `JavascriptExecute` -> `ClickElement` in order to get all the comments expanded. Is is possible to overcome this problem and ensure that all the comments will be expanded?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Web sites like this can be very dynamic: clicking one link affecting other links etc. So you may have to repeat the process, to be able to click on previously inaccessible links. Another problem could be that ClickElement is executing too fast for your browser to keep up with. In that case try adding small a small Pause[] between clicks.

Comment: Another question: is it possible to execute the `Save As...` dialog in Chrome?

Comment: It might be possible, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The problem with not all comments being expanded can be solved nicely if we simply replace the line `result[cnt++] = links[i];` with line `links[i].click();` in the JavaScript code. `ClickElement` with this approach isn't needed.

Comment: Yes, in fact this is true in general: you can achieve almost any interaction in a browser with javascript (and thus with JavascriptExecute). The ClickElement function relies on Chrome's webdriver technology, which is a bit of a black box (proxy) sitting in between the Wolfram Language and a browser.

Comment: This package no longer works on OSX in v11.1

Comment: I assume you have the latest release? https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/WebUnit/releases

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working workaround for the Internet Explorer COM automation (but I still don't understand why the straightforward `click[]` method shown in the question does not work).

The solution is to execute on the web page a Javascript code using the `javascript:` protocol. In [this post](https://greasyfork.org/en/forum/discussion/comment/24466/#Comment_24466) [Jefferson Scher](https://greasyfork.org/en/forum/profile/71/Jefferson%20Scher) suggested a very efficient `clickEm` Javascript function that clicks only on the top level <kbd>EXPAND</kbd> buttons which expand multiple children collapsed comments. His solution also has an advantage of being independent from the language settings of LiveJournal (the <kbd>EXPAND</kbd> buttons have different localized names depending on the language settings). Here is a bookmarklet with his code:

```
javascript:(function(){var elinks = document.querySelectorAll('.b-tree-twig-1 .b-leaf-actions-expandchilds > a'); for (var i=0; i<elinks.length; i++){elinks[i].click();}})();
```

Here is complete COM automation code:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];
ie = CreateCOMObject["InternetExplorer.Application"];
ie@visible = True;
ie@Navigate["http://suggestions.livejournal.com/825341.html"];
(* waiting while post is being loaded *)
While[ie@Busy, Pause[.1]];
ie@Navigate[
  "javascript:(function(){var elinks =     \
document.querySelectorAll('.b-tree-twig-1 .b-leaf-actions-expandchilds > a'); \
    for (var i=0; i<elinks.length; i++){elinks[i].click();}})();"]
doc = ie@Document;
(* waiting while expanded comments are being loaded *)
While[ie@Busy || doc@readyState =!= "complete", Pause[.1]];
```

(tested with Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 x64).