# Can Mathematica run javascript on a website?

Tags: web-access

One way of running Javascript on a website is to use for instance Greasemonkey. By any chance, would it be possible to execute Javascript commands from Mathematica?

Comment: See [WebUnit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69343/731). Also, if you want to evaluate JavaScript in general – not on a website – I'm guessing that [`ExternalEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) could be used together with NodeJS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is now possible in Mathematica 12.

For example , you can open a new tab in web browser using following code:

```
session = StartWebSession[]

WebExecute["OpenPage" -> "https://www.wolfram.com"]

WebExecute["JavascriptExecute" -> "window.open('https://www.wolframalpha.com', '_blank')"]
```

For additional information , visit : https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WebExecute.html

Answer (score 2):

It might be relevant, you can run both in the browser
https://github.com/JerryI/wljs-interpreter

Comment: WLJS does not work for me under macOS 14.0 -- neither the Electron cross-platform app nor the console/web-browser combination. I do have WolframEngine installed and  activated with Wolfram; I also have wolframscript and Mathematica. With fomer after all the downloading aftrer i open the app, I get a totally blank window in which I see nothing and can type nothing; with the console/browser combination, after `wolframscript -f Scripts/run.wls`I see af binary write error and then the indicated browser URL cannot be opened.

Comment: Hi, @murray. Please consider this guide https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs/docs/frontend/Troubleshooting.  May be a prebuilt binary of some internal libraries is missing for your WL + OS combo, but this is usually an easy fix :)