# Save file from URL using mathematica

Tags: import, save

Is there an easy way to download and save a .zip file from a URL to my computer through Mathematica? I am trying to develop an auto-update function for a mathematica package that is distributed via GitHub.

I tried `Import[http://github.com/******.zip]`, but that only gave me the names of the files in the folder, but not the actual files or a way to save them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `URLSave`?

Comment: You can try `Import[http://github.com/******.zip, "*"]` and check the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/ZIP.html).

Comment: @Pickett `URLSave` gave me the error code: `URLSave::invhttp: Failed writing received data to disk/application"`

@Karsten7. `Import` takes over 20 minutes to work, because I believe it is downloading, unzipping, and parsing the files, when I just need to save and unzip the file.

Thank you both for ideas though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I cannot post this as a comment, sorry.)*

Your question seems to be a duplicate of this one: [Downloading files without using Import](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/downloading-files-without-using-import).

I have just checked the solution from there, it downloads fine zip-files from GitHub. For extracting downloaded package, you can use ExtractArchive function.

Comment: Oh wow I don't know how I missed that. That's an even better fix! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Found an easy solution: Use `SystemOpen["https://github.com/****.zip"]`. This will open the file in the system browser, and start the download!

(Decided to post the solution here in case others have the same question)